# How can I update a DataGrid Column with the selectedvalue of a Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datagrid, html-select

I'am Using C# Web Application. I have a `DataGrid` that contains 4 columns. Three columns are labels and one is a DropDownList. In my ddl_SelectedIndexChanged I want to be able to take the selected value from my DDL (cell[3]) and place it in cell[2] of the same row.

This is what I have:

```
protected void ddlMachId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

    string val = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();

    TableCell cell = ddl.Parent as TableCell;
    DataGridItem item = cell.Parent as DataGridItem;

    item.Cells[2] = val;
}
```

This gives me an error saying item.Cells[2] is read only.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a **DataGrid**, do this:

```
protected void ddlMachId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;    
    TableCell cell = list.Parent as TableCell;
    DataGridItem item = cell.Parent as DataGridItem;

    string val = list.SelectedValue.ToString();
    item.Cells[2].Text = val; 
}
```

If you are using **GridView**, You have to use namingcontainer to get the gridview row:

```
protected void ddlMachId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

    string val = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
    row.Cells[2].Text = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try that:

```
//Get the actual row, and key for the column...
row.Cells[2].Value = val;
```

Comment: what is that? I don't have a row in that procedure and what is stars?

Comment: updated, the row can get from the datagrid actual selected row proerty